# Read a file in by columns in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have a file that contains numbers:

```
23 899 234 12
12 366 100 14
10 256 500 23
14 888 564 30
```

How can I read this file by column using C++? I searched YouTube but they only read file by row. If I have to find the highest value from the first column, I need to read it by columns right?

Comment: You could read line by line and store the values in a vector of vectors in which the outer vector is the rows and the inner vector is the columns. Then you can find the maximum value in a column by finding the maximum value in the corresponding inner vector.

Comment: "I need to read it by columns" - files are read character by character, therefore it's read line by line (a line is a bunch of characters (or none) ending with a line end (optional carriage return + line feed). You have to read a line, get first field/col, and ignore anything else until you get to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising a variable called column =0
Now when you access row iterate through column using a for loop until end of column which can be found out by no of lines in a file, then implement the operation what you are willing to do, now increase column no for going to next column.

And you can get value in form of n*vectors
Where n is no of rows
Dimension of vector is length of column

Answer (score 0):

Files are storages with sequential access, so , generally you have to read everything. Essentially it's like reading from a tape. And format of your file doesn't offer any shortcuts.

But, you can fast-forward and rewind along file, using seek() if it's a file on permanent storage. It's not effective and you have to know position where to go. If your records are of same size, you can advance by fixed amount of bytes.

That is usually done with binary formats and those formats are designed to have some kind directory or other auxiliary data to help searching for proper position..

Answer (score 0):

Read each line and split it by space and store the first value as highest value. repeat the steps for all rows until you reach end of file while comparing the first value again with already stored value as highest.

I don't have C++ compiler available with myself to test. it should work for you conceptually.

```
#include <fstream>

#include <string>

#include <iostream>

#include<sstream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  ifstream inFile("Read.txt");

  string line;
  int greatest = 0;
  while (getline(inFile, line)) {
    stringstream ss(line);
    string FirstColumn;

    while (ss >> FirstColumn) {
      if (stoi(FirstColumn) > greatest)
        greatest = stoi(FirstColumn);

    }
    cout << greatest << endl;
  }

}
```